# Every single app crash

Tags: android-studio, crash-reports

I get same error every single time i try to launch ANY project , can't figure it out by myself where's the problem. I used eclipse but now tried android-studio as well but it didnt fix error. Even if i create new project-on launching it will crash.

when it crash it says -unfortunately "app" has stopped-

http://pastebin.com/P3QNYyLg

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import

```
android.support.v7
```

There's great instructions on how to do so here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html